# Coupling probability and random walk game (2)

Tags: probability, probability-theory, random-variables, random-walk, geometric-probability

There are 3 players and one dealer in a casino. The dealer chooses a player randomly($p_1=\frac{1}{3}$). The chosen player tosses a coin($p_2=\frac{1}{2}$).

If the coin lands head, the chosen player will get 3 dollar, the dealer and the other two players will lose 1 dollar each.
If the coin lands tail, the chosen player will lose 3 dollar, the dealer and the other two players will get 1 dollar each.

This game repeats $n$ times. Let $x_{1n},x_{2n},x_{3n}$ be the total net profit(or loss) of players and let $y_n$ be the total net profit(or loss) of the dealer.

Let $g(n)=prob(|y_n|>max(|x_{in}|) )$

For example, $g(1)=0, g(3)=\frac{1}{18}$.

Prove: $g(n)$ is increasing as odd number $n$ goes $n+2$

comments: This question is similar with this question.
[a coupling probability problem and random walk game](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3861997/a-coupling-probability-problem-and-random-walk-game)
Only difference is $|y_n|>max(|x_{in}|)$ condition instead of $y_n>max(x_{in})$

Comment: How far have you gotten with this?

Comment: |y|>|x| doesn't mean "y is the biggest winner or the biggest loser". For example, y=2 and x1=-3. x2=-3, y is biggest winner but |y|<|x|

Comment: My bad.  Don't have my head on straight yet this morning, I guess.  Did you dispose of the "increasing" part of the prior question?

Comment: I think the previous question was solved by user's answers already. I am waiting to confirm the answer because of some reason. You can read the comments of the answers of the prior question.